# how do I listen isDrawerOpen on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to hide some widgets when the drawer opens. (it's mean when user open drawer then I need to hide some widgets)

Currently, I am using

```
  if(!_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen)
     //hide widget
```

But this is not `listen`. Is there any way to do listen drawer callbacks?

Comment: Question is not much clear? what you exactly want, either drawer open or not or not able to update anything?

Comment: @jitsm555 it's mean when user open drawer then I need to hide some widgets

Comment: @jitsm555 sorry for bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no callback mechanism till now in flutter which gives events for `Drawer()`, but still we can apply a good solution for it.

I divided the solution using two stateful widgets,

1. HomeScreen (Main Widget)
2. MyDrawer (Drawer Widget)

**1. HomeScreen:**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  bool _isDrawerOpen = false;

  void drawerCallback(bool isOpen) {
    print('Drawer Status:' + isOpen.toString());
    // Based on the bool value set visibility of your widget
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
      setState(() {
        _isDrawerOpen = isOpen;
      });

    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Nav Sample App')),
        body: _isDrawerOpen
            ? Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: Text('Drawer Open'))
            : Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: Text('Drawr Close')),
        drawer: MyDrawer(drawerCallback));
  }
}
```

Above you can see that based on `_isDrawerOpen` we are setting widgets in the body with the ternary operator.

**2. MyDrawer()**

```
class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function _drawerCallback;
  MyDrawer(this._drawerCallback);

  @override
  _MyDrawerState createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget._drawerCallback(true);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget._drawerCallback(false);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
          ),
          Text("Drawer Item 1"),
          Text("Drawer Item 2"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Heart of the logic is applied in `initState()` and `dispose()` callbacks where we are returning status.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onTap() function for drawers using a ListView:

```
Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Drawers'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Drawer 1'),
              onTap: () {
                // Insert code to hide or delete your desired widget

                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),//drawer
```

Comment: thanks..but the user can swipe left of the screen's edge and open drawer